# Can I run XPATH queries in Immediate window?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xpath, immediate-window

Is it possible to run XPATH queries on an active window which is an XML from the Immediate window?

(In my case, I would like to do it to see if I am selecting the correct nodes; but anyway, is it possible and how? Example?)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in Firefox. Install XPath addon and open the xml on firefox.

Comment: No that I know of. You can try http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx For IE you can also try http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html